# Deleting GoToMeeting Installer and GoToWebinar Opener.exe files on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall, adware, revo-uninstaller

I am using a computer with Windows 10.

Last Tuesday I was going to watch a webinar and it required me to install the [GoToWebinar](https://applauncher.gotowebinar.com) (from LogMeIn).

After finishing the Webinar, I deleted the Desktop shortcuts and went straight to the Control Panel and uninstalled what I had to install.

Once I started the computer on the next day, I have noticed that the file `GoToWebinar Opener.exe` was present.

I have followed [this procedure](https://support.logmeininc.com/gotoassist-corporate/help/uninstall-the-goto-opener-gta640005), restarted my machine, but the file was still there.

I have then, installed the software again and try to delete it using Revo Uninstaller Pro. It didn't work and now, I can't delete the following files:

• `GoToMeeting Installer.exe`

• `GoToWebinar Opener.exe`

[image: GoToWebinar Files that keep on popping up]

The program seems to be deleted, however I can't get rid of these files.

I have tried the following steps:

**1) Right click + Delete**

If I right click one of the files, let's use `GoToMeeting Installer.exe` as example, and press Delete, I appears the following:

[image: Right Click + Delete]

And, even though I am using an account with Admin rights, I get the following warning:

[image: Right Click + Delete with Admin]

Ps. This worked for a while, but, a bit after the files were deleted, they they kept on appearing again. Now, it says that I don't even have permissions to do it.

**2) Using Revo Uninstaller Pro**

As the program was uninstalled, it doesn't show, on Revo Uninstaller Pro, in the section "All Programs".

I have then used the Hunter Mode, to select the files, and press:

*2.1. Kill and Delete Process*

I get the following warning:

[image: Warning after Kill and Delete]

Which then gives me this message if I press "Yes":

[image: Permissions]

*2.2. Uninstall*

I end up with the following warning.

[image: Uninstall warnning]

---

The files are not recognized as a treat by Windows Defender and Malwarebytes.

**Any advice on how to get rid of these files is appreciated.**

---

**Edit 1: Using Autoruns**

[image: Autoruns]

Comment: Get Autoruns from Microsoft SysInternals, install and run it. Disable this particular item. Once done, go to Control Panel, Programs and Features, uninstall again. Restart and see if it has been removed.

Comment: @John Autoruns already scanned everything. It doesn't have yellow warnings. Also, can't seem to find the specific files. In the Control Panel the program doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: Make sure you are using Autoruns and not Autoronsc. The list should be static once loaded. Look for go to meeting.  Also (given the above) do a full scan with Windows Defender.

Comment: @John check [Edit 1](https://superuser.com/revisions/1538686/2) - it is Autoruns and it cannot find "gotomeeting".

Comment: It may be a virus you downloaded. Scan fully with Windows Defender. Proper Go To Meeting uninstalls properly

Comment: @John I am running a full scan on Windows Defender. Will let you know as soon as I see the result of the scan.

Comment: Boot into Safe Mode or there is always [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)

Comment: @John after running the Full Windows Defender, it recognized 5 threats (including some Trojans). Unfortunately I didn't take a screenshot as I took action on them as soon as I saw it. As a prevention, I will factory reset this machine.
Feel free to add as an answer (and beware of the difference in the file names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you provided and the initial explanations were not part of the issue. So at this point, it appears to be a virus (looking at the filenames) you downloaded. Scan fully with Windows Defender.

A proper "Go To Meeting" installation uninstalls properly.